# What's wrong with my syntax inserting JSON into mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a JSON column and i am using the following syntax...

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myJSONColumn) VALUES (["test1", "test2", "test3"])
```

Every resource i can find seems to say the above should be correct. What am i missing?

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong? Are you getting an error?  If so, it might be helpful if you shared that error with us

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '["string1","string2","string3"])' at line 1

Comment: Every resource? The offical doc doesn't show this syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to insert single value (one column), so put everything in '' like:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myJSONColumn) VALUES ('["test1", "test2", "test3"]')
```

Comment: Thanks, could have sworn i tried that but now it seems to work.